# Binary Search Tree's K[] preOrder() method: about the generic return

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Implementation Use: Data Structure Lab Exercise for October/28/2011
To do: Implement a Binary Search Tree

Problem: K[] return of methods preOrder(), inOrder() and postOrder()

Problem Details:
The BST must only have its root as a parameter. The methods above mentioned have been described in an interface given by our professor as the following:

```
    /**
    * Returns an array of keys filled according
    * to the pre-order traversing in a BST.  
    */      
    public K[] preOrder();      
    public K[] order();         
    public K[] postOrder();
```

I could instantiate the generic array with the following code:

```
public K[] preOrder() {

    if (root == null) { return null; }

    ArrayList<K> list = new ArrayList<K>();
    preOrderRecursive(root,list);
    K[] toReturn = (K[]) Array.newInstance(this.getRoot().getKey().getClass(), list.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        toReturn[i] = list.get(i);
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

But, when i tested the method using a testing class also provided by our professor, i got a nullPointerException, wich i think is referring to the root of the BST, that has been once instantiated, but has been removed at a point in the test, and when it calls the method again, the method returns null, not an empty array as expected by the test:

```
    (...)

    tree1 = new BSTImpl<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        tree1.insert(i, i);
    }
    tree1.remove(1);
    tree1.remove(2);
    tree1.remove(3);
    tree1.remove(4);
    assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{},tree1.preOrder());

    (...)
```

Knowing that i can't change the return type nor the parameters of the method, what can i do to avoid this Exception? Can i somehow get the component type and use it to instantiate the empty array (how'd i do this?)?

Any tips to improve my code are also welcome.

Comment: You are using `array.size` in your `newInstance` expression when creating the array , but not sure what the `array` refers to. You then go on to use list.size() to fill the `K[]`. Have you made sure the `array.size` actually has non zero length ?

Comment: it was a simple mistake: i used the variable name "array" to name the list, when i was posting here, i renamed all variables to a self-explaining name, but forgot to rename it there. the expression "array.size()" refers to the list, instead of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is: Do you really *need* an *Integer* array returned? - I don't think so.

I assume `assertArrayEquals()` does *not* check the component type of the arrays but rather only compares the contained values.

With the code you showed, I'd say anything else would not be possible due to type erasure.

So try to return an `Object[]` or whatever super-type applies in your case:

`return new Object[0];`

and

`return list.toArray();`

(unchecked casts required, but that should be o.k.)

EDIT:

Ok, so `<K extends Comparable>`?
In that case use:

`return new Comparable[0];`

and

`return (Comparable[])list.toArray(new Comparable[]);`

Comment: I thought about it, but it isn't that simple. The method can't return an object, it has to return a comparable.

Comment: The array itself is *never* comparable, the values contained *may* be. And in your case they *are* comparable because you're putting *Integer* objects into the array. Did you try my approach? - As I tried to explain: You can, of course, use *new Integer[0];* or whatever fits the expected (super-)type.

Comment: I tried it, but to no avail. If it returns an Object, it throws a ClassCastException because the class compares the keys to find out where to insert a new node, so it needs to be a class that implements the Comparable interface. Doing it my way, it won't pass the test because when the root is null it returns a null array and not an array of the elements' class, as the test ask. Remember i cann't change the method's return, nor parameter nor the test. I was only hoping there's some way to tell the code i want it not a null array, but an empty array of whatever be the class of the tree's keys.